# Editing Recurring Events in Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I don't understand how this works
as you see in the first image, this is a recurring event that ends after 4 days,
I changed the start time of the first one.

but later I decided that I want this recurring event to end after 3 days

after I've changed the series, the changes that I made to the first one is gone!

how can I prevent this to happen. I want the changes that I made to specific days to stay even after I change the recurring series.
thanks
[image: calendar1]
[image: calendar2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this behavior is by design. Even an alert is shown as you try change the recurring events, stating that all exceptions would be lost. After changes in the series, you should re-create the exceptions. You can automate the re-creation of exceptions (for example, via PowerShell), but based on your case it may be easier to manually alter the single exception.

You can change the number of occurence in the series via PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursite
$list = $web.Lists["YourCalendar"]
$item = $list.GetItemById(33) # use the actual item id of the master event here
$item["RecurrenceData"] = '<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency="1" /></repeat><repeatInstances>3</repeatInstances></rule></recurrence>'
$item.Update()
```

For an overview of the most important fields of recurring event see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434156.aspx).

Comment: so how can I add a meeting's specific detail after it's over without it being deleted when I make changes to the series later?

Comment: I'm afraid, you can do that only via code. As you probably know, the master event and exceptions of the recurring events are all stored as separate items in the list (see the All Events view of thje Calendar). If you edit a recurring event the system does not know which values are to take over, and which not, so I think MS chose the simplest way when decided to remove all exceptions in this case.